# According to the documentation throwing an error in a promise will reject it, but it does not

Tags: javascript, promise

> Throwing an Error will also reject the promise
>
> ```
> throw new Error(reason);
> ```

I tried that here:

```js
const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
 var result = 1;

 // This could also be a web request, or anything else either synchronous or asynchronous
 setTimeout(function() {
  result += 10;

  resolve(result);
 },3000);

 document.body.addEventListener("click", function clickHandler() {
  document.body.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);
        
                // HERE I AM THROWING AN ERROR!
  throw new Error("You clicked");
 });

 document.body.innerText = "Working... Click anywhere to reject the promise with an error.";
});

promise.then(function(value) {
 document.body.innerText = "Everything went fine! The Promise resolved with: " + value;
}).catch(function(error) {
 document.body.innerText = "Something went wrong: " + error;
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But it ends up with an error and resolves fine.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you threw an error in a callback..

Comment: That thrown error is not in the promise, by the time that click is fired, that code has finished executing.

Comment: Yes... but within the promise @KevinB

Comment: well, no, the promise callback had long since returned, and isn't waiting on anything so it continues on.

Comment: You're throwing the error from a click event handler, that has *nothing* to do with the promise

Comment: Hmmm interesting. I guess someone should note that in the docs @KevinB

Comment: It is my error @Amit -- I had assumed since the function was defined within the Promise callback itself that it would bubble up to a rejection.

Comment: it's already documented there. *"It is possible to throw an exception that is not handled by the promise by wrap the throw statement inside a setTimeout callback: `<snip>`
**This works because promises cannot handle exceptions thrown asynchronously**."*

Comment: @KevinB do you have a link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises/2811/error-handling#t=201608111907503760823 4 code blocks down

Comment: Hmm ok. The docs for the intro should probably have a link to that @KevinB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not throwing the error within the context of the promise, you error is happening within the context of the click handler, **after** you create the promise.

```
const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    document.body.addEventListener("click", function clickHandler() {
        // this is not part of the promise and executes sometime later
    });
});
```

This means the code within the promise, including the attachment of the listener, will happen when the promise is created and no errors happen at that time.

Sometime later, whenever your click event fires, you will throw an error asynchronously, within a completely separate context.

```
const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Any error that happens here will result in a promise rejection

    document.body.addEventListener("click", function clickHandler() {
        // Any error that happens here will be thrown within the handler,
        // after the promise was created and resolved
    });
});
```